# Audio to multiple HDMI sinks

Tags: pulseaudio, hdmi

I have 2 HDMI monitors connected to my laptop, and both of them display just fine. However, I want to play audio on both of them at the same time as well. I saw this post: [How to output unique audio to multiple ports/profiles of a PulseAudio card?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401492/how-to-output-unique-audio-to-multiple-ports-profiles-of-a-pulseaudio-card/401562#401562?newreg=a2c8d4c42a4944e1935687f0f0251994)

I have attempted the solution described in the answer, of editing the pulseaudio confs to create a new profile. However, when I tried setting it, it said no such profile:

```
No such profile: output:analog-stereo+output:hdmi-stereo+output:hdmi-stereo+output:hdmi-stereo
```

I was wondering if anyone else had a similar experience.

Comment: I have written about this. Check out my answer here. https://askubuntu.com/a/1446236/360963

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and quickest way is to simply load a loopback.

`pactl load-module module-loopback`

**1)** Then in `pavucontrol` in **Playback**, if you have a video playing with VLC for example, you will have two outputs: **VLC Media Player** and **Loopback of Monitor..* that will each allow you to pick a different output.

**2)** You should set the VLC Media to output on one device **[Device 1]** available in the Configuration tab, and then set the second newly-available **Loopback Monitor of [Device 1]** to output on the second **[Device 2]**.

**3)** Finally, in the **Recording** tab make sure that you have set the:

**Loopback to... [Device 2]** to source its stream from **[Monitor of Device 1]** .

**EDIT:** I hope you were specifically looking to output the same audio to two different outputs i.e. both monitors playing the same audio. Otherwise, if you are looking to simply have two distinct outputs, then the process is even more straightforward and running `pactl load-module module-udev-detect` should find all the available cards and corresponding outputs for you for `pavucontrol` . As long as you don't have a single HDMI output running through a splitter to output the same exact video to multiple different screens (for example some group display/conferencing system where others watch your screen output on multiple tv sets connected to your display directly through an HDMI splitter etc.) `udev-detect` should create the configuration on its own.

Comment: OP didn't describe the hardware configuration, but often you have an Intel HDA where some codec outputs are connected to the graphic card, and the graphic card then mixes them with the HDMI data. Which means the first problem is to configure the codec to allow two sound streams to HDMI in the first place. Which is why he's asking for a particular **profile**. Once you actually *have* two different Pulseaudio sinks for HDMI, then your solution would apply. But the question is if one can get those at all. Though I'd rather use `module-combine-sink` in this case.