# Pulseaudio two outputs in one profile don't work proper

Tags: ubuntu, pulseaudio, kiosk

i want to output the sound on HDMI and DP.
To archiev this, i searched how to do it and found this: [How to output unique audio to multiple ports/profiles of a PulseAudio card?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401492/how-to-output-unique-audio-to-multiple-ports-profiles-of-a-pulseaudio-card)

I followed the answer from @dirkt and created a new profile in `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/default.conf`.

```
[Profile output:hdmi-stereo+output:hdmi-stereo-extra1]
description = Both
output-mappings = hdmi-stereo hdmi-stereo-extra1
input-mappings =
```

I verified this is working with the gui `pavucontrol` and it seems working.
I had a new profile called `Both` under the `Configuration` Tab and under `Output Devices` i can see both (HDMI and DP).

But if i play music the sound will be played on the monitor which is connected via DP.
No sound on the monitor via HDMI.

Attached a image from `pavucontrol` (yea i know no screenshot, it's a kiosk system ^^).
[image]

Do i miss something ?
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
`pacmd list-cards:`

```
1 card(s) available.
index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
            alsa.card = "0"
            alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
            alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1320000 irq 140"
            alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
            device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
            sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
            device.bus = "pci"
            device.vendor.id = "8086"
            device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
            device.product.id = "a3f0"
            device.form_factor = "internal"
            device.string = "0"
            device.description = "Built-in Audio"
            module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
            device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
            output:hdmi-stereo+output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Both (priority 0, available: unknown)
            input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: no)
            output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
            output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
            output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: unknown)
            output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5460, available: unknown)
            output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5200, available: unknown)
            output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: unknown)
            output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
            output:hdmi-stereo+output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Both (priority 0, available: unknown)
            input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: no)
            output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
            output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
            output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: unknown)
            output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5460, available: unknown)
            output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5200, available: unknown)
            output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: unknown)
            output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
            output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: no)
            output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
            output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: no)
            output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
            output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: no)
            output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
            output:hdmi-stereo-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: no)
            output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: no)
            output:hdmi-surround-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: no)
            output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: no)
            output:hdmi-surround71-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: no)
            output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
            output:hdmi-stereo-extra4+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: no)
            output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
            output:hdmi-surround-extra4+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: no)
            output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
            output:hdmi-surround71-extra4+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 160, available: no)
            off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo+output:hdmi-stereo-extra1>
    sinks:
            alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo/#0: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
            alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo-extra1/#2: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
    sources:
            alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
            alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor/#2: Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
    ports:
            hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
                    properties:
                            device.icon_name = "video-display"
            hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
                    properties:
                            device.icon_name = "video-display"
                            device.product.name = "EV2416W"
            analog-input-headphone-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                    properties:
                            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            analog-input-headset-mic: Headset Microphone (priority 8800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                    properties:
                            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                    properties:

            analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                    properties:
                            device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
            analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                    properties:
                            device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
            hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                    properties:
                            device.icon_name = "video-display"
            hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                    properties:
                            device.icon_name = "video-display"
            hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                    properties:
                            device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

Comment: It is possible that your HDMI codec doesn't support using two outputs at the same time. The original question was for an Intel HDA codec, where this usually works. To debug this, have a look at `/proc/card*/codec#*`, pick your HDMI codec, and have a look at the nodes and connections. Also, sometimes the graphics card is involved in this, too, which adds additional restrictions (and no standard way to find out what is going on).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, under the path `/proc` is nothing which starts with `card`.
I'm not sure if it helps, but the system is a DELL optiplex 3080.
In `pavucontrol` the "sound level" also don't show anything for the DP for HDMI it change (based on the Volume - see the image).

Is there a other way how i can debug it :-) ?

Comment: Added the result of the `pacmd list-cards` command, which also shows `HDA Intel PCH`.